# Regex match whole words with special characters

Tags: python, regex

I have a string (csv) like this:

```
american, american , latin-american, American, AMERICAN
```

I have tried this `\bamerican\b` but it matches all five words. It seems like it ignores some special characters like "-" and " ". It is also case-insensitive.

What it is supposed to do is ignore only the ",". It also has to be case-sensitive.

So the only match word was "american" (the first word on that string).

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What programming language do you use ?

Comment: `(?i)(\blatin-\b)*\bamerican\b` does it satisfy you?

Comment: if all those words separted by comma, then you can split by comma and then search for `american`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
(?:^|(?<=,\s))american(?:(?=,)|$)
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/g9DiXr/1)

```
import re
txt = 'american, american , latin-american, American, AMERICAN'
re.findall('(?:^|(?<=,\s))american(?:(?=,)|$)', txt)

//Output: ['american'] the first one.
```